# KornShell Regular Expression

Tags: regex, ksh

How can I match part of a string using a regular expression in ksh scripts?

I have a string coming into my script which could be something like this: 
`/data/inform/far_proj/scripts/../SrcFiles/load_alfa_data.dat`

I have searched for a bit on how to do a regular expression in KornShell, but I haven't been successful. What I have is this: I am looking to see if the string contains `load_alfa_data`

```
if [[ $FILENAME = @("load_alfa_data") ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ksh` you can do `case`:

```
case "$FILENAME" in
  *load_alfa_data*) echo "found load_alfa_data" ;;
  *)                echo "nope" ;;
esac
```

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator in the builtin `[[` command is a pattern match operator

```
if [[ $FILENAME == *load_alfa_data* ]]; then ...
```

Your pattern `@("load_alfa_data")` does not contain any wildcards, so it's basically doing exact string matching.

Get out of the habit of using ALL_CAPS_VARS: one day you'll write `PATH=/tmp/foo` and then wonder why your script is broken.